# KivyMD ScreenManager not chaging Scrren

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to change the screen when pressing the Login Button, but nothing is happening. I tried every possible way I was able to find online, but nothing worked. I want to switch the screen from my python file and not from the kv file because I want to authenticate the login.

Python File:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass
class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name = 'login'))
sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name = 'main'))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        kv = Builder.load_file('app.kv')
        return kv
    def login(self):
        sm.current = "main"

if __name__== '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    MainWindow:

<LoginWindow>:
    name: 'login'
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 400
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 4
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'
    
        MDLabel:
            id: welcome_lable
            text: "Tracker"
            font_size: 40
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 15

        MDTextField:
            id: user
            mode: 'round'
            hint_text: "Nutzername"
            icon_right: "account"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

        MDTextField:
            id: password
            mode: 'round'
            hint_text: "Passwort"
            icon_right: "key"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            password: True

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            id: login
            text: "Anmelden"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: app.login()

        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 10
    
<MainWindow>: 
    name: 'main'
    MDLabel:
        id: welcome_lable
        text: "Willkommen"
        font_size: 40
        halign: 'center'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        padding_y: 15
```

I am trying to change the screen when pressing the Login Button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `login()` method changes the `current` screen of the `sm` (`ScreenManager`). However, that `sm` is not part of your GUI and is never actually used by your `App`. You entire GUI is defined by your `app.kv` file. A simple fix is to change your `login()` method:

```
def login(self):
    # sm.current = "main"
    self.root.current = "main"
```

And the code:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name = 'login'))
sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name = 'main'))
```

can be eliminated, since it is not actually used.